# Deploy Mongo Database with a single master and two read replicas in the Kubernetes cluster of at least 3 worker nodes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

Deploy Mongo Database with a single master and two read replicas in the Kubernetes cluster of at least 3 worker nodes that are available in different availability zones.

Points to keep in mind while deploying the DB:

- All replicas of DB should be deployed in a separate worker node of diff Availability    Zone(For high availability).
- Autoscale the read replicas if needed.
- Data should be persistent.
- Try to run the containers in nonprivileged mode if possible.
- Use best practices as much as you can.

Push the task into a separate branch with a proper README file.

Comment: I assume this is more of an informational post?

Comment: @GariSingh  It is related to my assignment  ....